# R: summarise with linear regression

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with a yearly average over several items.

**data have:**

```
df <- data.frame(item  = c(1, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2,  3, 3, 3, 3,  4, 4, 4, 4),
                 year  = c(1, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3, 4)
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 3,  2, 3, 4, 0,  1, 1, 3, 2,  2, 1, 1, 2))
```

I need to produce a simple linear regression model, between the year and average, separately for each item.

**data want:**

```
| year |  slope |  intercept |
|:----:|:------:|:----------:|
|    1 |   0.7  |        0.5 |
|    2 |  -0.2  |        3.0 |    
|    3 |   0.5  |        0.5 |  
|    4 |   0.0  |        1.5 |
```

**my attempt:**

I believe it could be done with some combination of group_by(), summarise() amd lm().

so I tried doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarise(slope     = unname(lm(value ~ year, data=df)[[1]])[2],
            intercept = unname(lm(value ~ year, data=df)[[1]])[1])
```

but it returns the same slope and intercept for all lines.
In other words, group_by was not applied.

Thus, my questions are:

- How can the grouping be achieved?
- How can the calculation be applied
  to each item separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `lm( ..., data=df)` you still use the same df object you started with, to make your own approach work you would need to replace it with something that's aware of the context (i.e. grouping) and returns the current data for the current group: [`cur_data()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html)

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(item  = c(1, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2,  3, 3, 3, 3,  4, 4, 4, 4),
                 year  = c(1, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3, 4),
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 3,  2, 3, 4, 0,  1, 1, 3, 2,  2, 1, 1, 2))

df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarise(slope     = unname(lm(value ~ year, data=cur_data())[[1]])[2],
            intercept = unname(lm(value ~ year, data=cur_data())[[1]])[1])
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>    item slope intercept
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1   0.7       0.5
#> 2     2  -0.5       3.5
#> 3     3   0.5       0.5
#> 4     4   0         1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I'm choosing this answer because it's the most readable to me, but it seems all answers here are useful

Answer (score 3):

You may try `by`.

```
data.frame(unique(df$item), t(sapply(by(df, df$item, lm, fo=value ~ year), coef))) |>
  `colnames<-`(c('year', 'intercept', 'slope'))
#   year intercept slope
# 1    1       0.5   0.7
# 2    2       3.5  -0.5
# 3    3       0.5   0.5
# 4    4       1.5   0.0
```

Perhaps easier to understand, but yields the same:

```
by(df, df$item, lm, fo = value ~ year) |>
  sapply(coef) |>
  t() |>
  data.frame(unique(df$item)) |>
  `colnames<-`(c('intercept', 'slope', 'year'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(item) %>% 
do(reg = lm(value ~ year, data = .)$coefficients) %>%
unnest_wider(reg)
```

gives,

```
#   item `(Intercept)`   year
#  <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1         0.500  0.7  
#2     2         3.50  -0.500
#3     3         0.5    0.5  
#4     4         1.5    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `tidy` and converting the results to wider format using `pivot_wider` like this (you could add more results like p-value):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(value ~ year, data = .))) %>%
  select(item, term, estimate) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = estimate) %>%
  rename(slope = year, intercept = `(Intercept)`)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   item [4]
#>    item intercept slope
#>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1       0.5   0.7
#> 2     2       3.5  -0.5
#> 3     3       0.5   0.5
#> 4     4       1.5   0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution (quite verbose) using `group_split` to make lists, then use `map_dfr` to iterate over each list. Get the tidy output with `broom`s `tidy()` and finally bring in shape:

```
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(item = factor(item)) %>% 
  group_split(item) %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lm(value ~ year, data = df) %>% 
      tidy() %>% 
      add_column(item = unique(df$item), .before = 1)
  }) %>% 
  mutate(term = str_replace_all(term, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")) %>% 
  select(item, term, estimate) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = term,
              values_from = estimate)
```

```
  item  Intercept  year
  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 1           0.5   0.7
2 2           3.5  -0.5
3 3           0.5   0.5
4 4           1.5   0
```